# Rewriting a url on a shared hosting platform (Perch CMS)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been working on this all day and haven't found anything that works. my current url is

http://myurl.com/blog/post.php?s=2016-08-30-test-8

and i'd like it to look like this

http://beecrowned.com/blog/2016-08-30-test-8

I'm currently using this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on  
    RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/post.php?s=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it hasn't worked, any ideas?

Comment: Where have you defined the rewrite rule?

Comment: Have you the .htaccess file in a subfolder?  Your example works for me in the document root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it in root directory,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)$ blog/post.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```